# Why is my try catch solution not working as I expect it

Tags: python, django, openstack-keystone

I am trying to validate a form in a django project and part of the validation is to check if a project exists.

**The Environment:**

```
python 3.6.3
django 1.10.8
python-keystoneclient 3.14.0
```

I have this check currently

```
def clean_projectname(self):
        submitted_data = self.cleaned_data['projectname']
        newproj = "PROJ-FOO" + submitted_data.upper()
        keystone = osauth.connect()
        try:
            project = keystone.projects.find(name=newproj)
            raise forms.ValidationError('The project name is already taken')
        except NotFound:
            return submitted_data
```

The try section will return either a project object or it will have a 404 not found Exception.

I have tried to except on the NotFound but Django gives me an error

```
name 'NotFound' is not defined
```

I would appreciate help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you imported `NotFound` from `python-keystoneclient`? The only way your code would work is if you had this line somewhere else in your file:

```
from keystoneclient.exceptions import NotFound
```

Comment: That was my mistake Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of the NotFound Exception. Is it something you've written yourself or perhaps you meant to use a similar sound Django exception?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/exceptions/

Comment: Didn't notice this involved the python-keystoneclient. Andrew Hare's solution is better.

Comment: Thanks for answering I appreciate it